# Add bibliography after each chapter in CleanthesisTemplate

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am really new to Overleaf and Latex, I just know the basics of Latex. I am using clean thesis style ([link](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/)) for my thesis. I want to include bibliography at the end of each chapter. I tried sectionbib and chapterbib as well. But it is not working for me.

Can anyone explain, where I make changes in the clean thesis template to get bibliography at the end of each chapter, and not at the end of thesis.

One thing more. I want to do it by having

1. One bib file for whole thesis (to avoid duplicates)
2. Each chapter includes its own specific references in the bibliography

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide the code of what you have tried. This makes it easier to determine what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, I tried the chapterbib in the options of cleanthesis. Now it works like a charm :-)

This is my updated code

```
\usepackage[                    
    figuresep=colon,%
    sansserif=false,%
    hangfigurecaption=false,%
    hangsection=true,%
    hangsubsection=true,%
    colorize=full,%
    colortheme=bluemagenta,%
    bibsys=biber,%
    bibfile=bib-refs,%
    bibstyle=authoryear,%   
    refsection = chapter, 
    defernumbers = true 
]{cleanthesis}
```