# Bibliography for individual chapter in Texstudio (MacOS)

Tags: bibliographies, xetex, overleaf

I am writing thesis chapter with individual bibliography. Executing with Xelatex, and I found no errors, preview shows everything but citations and reference. Although, I have written report with citation it works fine.

However, I googled for solution but all ways failed, some of are [Post1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550109/individual-chapter-bibliographies-with-single-bib-source) [Post2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620610/chapterbib-changes-numbering-of-references-into-letters-chapterbibsectionbiba) [Post3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562367/add-bibliography-after-each-chapter-in-cleanthesistemplate)

Here is a simplest example of thesis from overleaf page which works on overleaf , but doesn't work on TexStudio(MacTex). any suggestion will be appreciated.

main.tex

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
%!BIB program = bibtex

\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\title{Per-chapter bibliographies with chapterbib}


\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}
\include{chap1}


\end{document}
```

chap1.tex

```
\chapter{First Chapter}

This example chapter, here's a citation! \citep{greenwade93}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{sample}
```

sample.bib

```
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
```

This was tried with MacTex and Texstudio in MacOS.

Results

[image]

[image]

Works fine in Overleaf website

[image]

Comment: Overleaf compiles using `latexmk` which does all the required compilations for you. Try changing your TeXStudio preferences to use `latexmk`. See [TexStudio with LuaLatex and latexmk - is this possible?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/351711). (Since you're not using `lualatex` you need to adjust the answer in that question to use `pdflatex` instead.